# A complicated definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I have the following integral to compute

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{A} \frac{1}{(4 \pi)} \Big[ \text{erf}\Big(\frac{k M - x + 2 \pi}{\sqrt{2} k S}\Big) -  \text{erf}\Big(\frac{k M - x}{\sqrt{2} k S}\Big)  \Big] dx $$

Where $\text{erf}$ is the error function. Mathematica does compute the indefinite integral, but not the definite one like this. If I see the indefinite integral, it looks like that at $-\infty$, the function is not converging. However, looking at the function, I feel at $-\infty$, the integrand of this must be $0$.

The indefinite integral from Mathematica:

$$\frac{1}{4\pi} \Bigg[ \left(k M-x\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{k \mu_{\omega}-x}{\sqrt{2} k S}\right) \\ +\left(-k M+x-2 \pi \right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{k M-x+2 \pi }{\sqrt{2} k S}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} k S \left(e^{-\frac{\left(x-k M\right)^2}{2 k^2 S^2}}-e^{-\frac{\left(k M-x+2 \pi \right)^2}{2 k^2 S^2}}\right) \Bigg] $$

================== EDIT based on –
user293787's comment:

I am trying the following input:

```
L[x_]  := 1/(4 Pi) ( 
   Erf[(k M - x + 2 Pi)/(Sqrt[2] k S)] -  Erf[(k M - x )/(Sqrt[2] k S)] )

Integrate[L[x], {x, -Infinity, A}]
```

Comment: The definite integral `Integrate[Erf[2*Pi-x]-Erf[-x],{x,-Infinity,A}]` is evaluated immediately. Please provide the code that does not return a result, you may just have created confusion with all your constants and simply need the appropriate `Assumptions`.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP probably has information about `k` and `S` that should be conveyed to Mathematica via `Assumptions`. This will make it easier for `Integrate` to decide, for example, if an integral converges or not.

Two examples:

- If `k` and `S` are both positive, one can use:

```
Integrate[L[x],{x,-Infinity,A},
          Assumptions->{k>0,S>0}]
```

- If `k` and `S` are real and nonzero, one can use:

```
Integrate[L[x],{x,-Infinity,A},
          Assumptions->{Element[k|S,Reals],k!=0,S!=0}]
```

Both these `Integrate` are evaluated explicitly and give a result in terms of `Erf`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was looking for this. This solved my issue. For me, S was non negative real number and k an integer greater than 0. I used these assumptions.